# Splitting an network block

Tags: java, networking, ip

How to split a network block to sub blocks in Java. I want to find out from a given 67.10/16 block, what blocks of /18 can I generate. For e.g. output should be this..

```
67.10.0/18
67.10.64/18
67.10.128/18
67.10.192/18
```

Or If I input 67.10/16 and the target cidr of /17 then the output should be

```
67.10.0/17
67.10.128/17
```

What is the best and efficient way of doing this.
Thank You

Comment: Or better yet, is there any java APIS available to manage IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example - subnet 67.10.1.1 /16 into four blocks.
In general:

Convert the base IP address to a number.

01000011 00001010 00000001 00000001 (1,124,729,089)

Convert the base mask to a number.

11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000 (4,294,901,760)

Mask the base IP with the mask giving the **true base IP**.

01000011 00001010 00000000 00000000 (1,124,728,832)

Convert the new mask (/18) to a number

11111111 11111111 11000000 00000000 (4,294,950,912)

XOR the original mask and the new mask to get the **addition factor**

00000000 00000000 11000000 00000000 (49,152)

Starting with the **true base IP**

```
for x = 0 to (2^(new cidr-old cidr))-1
 use **true base IP**
 true base IP = true base IP + addition factor
next x
```

Comment: Thank you for an outline. My apologies, I am not strong with bitwise operators. Do you mind showing me how would go about using XOR and also, since we have binary value, how do I do the addition. Thanks again.

Comment: I am not a java person, but once the IP addresses and mask's are converted to numbers it should be easy.  I know java has an XOR.

Comment: No worries, Let me ask you this. In the loop that you mentioned, I don't see 'true base IP' changing. As I understand, Incase of breaking out /18 out of /16, This will loop twice. one for 17 and another for 18. Do I need to do entire routine again, which is to make mask and getting true IP out at every iteration?

Comment: (2^(18-16))-1 = 3.  0 to 3 = 4.  Each loop will add 11000000 00000000 (49,152).